# Using an iPhone as FIDO2 hardware token?

Tags: iphone, authentication, nfc

There are many FIDO2 security hardware tokens on the market that allow password-less login on web sites e.g. on your PC. For example from YubiKey, FEITIAN, ePass...

These token communicate for example via NFC with the PC. But I don't want to use an extra token, when I have my iPhone which could do the job as well.

Is it possible to use an iPhone as a FIDO2 hardware token instead of those tiny hardware FIDO2 tokens? Is this possible with a plain iPhone running iOS 14.6 or do I need a special app so that the iPhone could act as authenticator?

I am aware that this would not work for authentication of web site in Safari on the iPhone, I only want the iPhone for FIDO2 authentication of my PC.

Comment: Have you searched the app store for FIDO2, there seem to be at least a couple...

Comment: @SteveChambers There may be some FIDO2 authenticator apps but none of them mentions NFC which is required for communication with the PC. An if the do NFC is just used for communication with an hardware NFC token. Therefore the roles are totally different to what I am searching.

Comment: It seems like there are no apps because Appl restricts access to the required functionality of NFC which is called Host Card Emulation (HCE). Without that API nobody is able to make an iPhone act like a NFC token (or client) which would be required for using the iPhone as FIDO2 hardware token.

Comment: Seems to be working [with iOS 16](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iphf538ea8d0/16.0/ios/16.0), but my iPhone is too old to test, so cannot confirm.